# Missing Microsoft.Web.Administartion in .net 4.5

Tags: vb.net, iis, iis-7, servermanager

My Project is set to .Net4.5 , but for some odd reason i am not able to import the above namespace in as it doesnt seem to exist.

I have the dlls inside intsrv folders and dont have option of changing the proj type.
Any idea how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add these dll's are references in the solution.

Solution Explorer -> Add Reference 
Microsoft.Web.Management
Microsoft.Web.Administration

Comment: Yup that was it. I had to add it in. Thanks